# Inner Class Breaks Eclipse Code Completion

Tags: java, eclipse, inner-classes, code-completion, jvm-bytecode

I am having a serious problem with Eclipse disabling *all* code completions in a Java class that imports a binary. The binary file was compiled by a custom compiler for a custom JVM-based programming language, and the code looks like this:

```
package dyvil.dyn

import  dyvil.lang.Map.Entry

public class Test[A, B] implements Entry[A, B]
{
    public A getKey() = null

    public B getValue() = null
}
```

`Entry` is an interface inside the `Map` interface, and both are written in **Java**. The compiler obviously has no trouble with this code, and produces the following bytecode (from `javap`):

```
public class dyvil.dyn.Test<A extends java.lang.Object, B extends java.lang.Object> extends java.lang.Object implements dyvil.lang.Map$Entry<A, B>
  Signature: #3                           // <A:Ljava/lang/Object;B:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ldyvil/lang/Map$Entry<TA;TB;>;
  InnerClasses:
       public static #10= #7 of #9; //Entry=class dyvil/lang/Map$Entry of class dyvil/lang/Map
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               dyvil/dyn/Test
   #2 = Class              #1             //  dyvil/dyn/Test
   #3 = Utf8               <A:Ljava/lang/Object;B:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ldyvil/lang/Map$Entry<TA;TB;>;
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Class              #4             //  java/lang/Object
   #6 = Utf8               dyvil/lang/Map$Entry
   #7 = Class              #6             //  dyvil/lang/Map$Entry
   #8 = Utf8               dyvil/lang/Map
   #9 = Class              #8             //  dyvil/lang/Map
  #10 = Utf8               Entry
  #11 = Utf8               <init>
  #12 = Utf8               ()V
  #13 = NameAndType        #11:#12        //  "<init>":()V
  #14 = Methodref          #5.#13         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #15 = Utf8               this
  #16 = Utf8               Ldyvil/dyn/Test<TA;TB;>;
  #17 = Utf8               Ldyvil/dyn/Test;
  #18 = Utf8               getKey
  #19 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  #20 = Utf8               getValue
  #21 = Utf8               Code
  #22 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #23 = Utf8               LocalVariableTypeTable
  #24 = Utf8               Signature
  #25 = Utf8               ()TA;
  #26 = Utf8               ()TB;
  #27 = Utf8               InnerClasses
{
  public dyvil.dyn.Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return        
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       4     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       4     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test<TA;TB;>;
    Signature: #12                          // ()V

  public A getKey();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aconst_null   
         1: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test<TA;TB;>;
    Signature: #25                          // ()TA;

  public B getValue();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aconst_null   
         1: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Ldyvil/dyn/Test<TA;TB;>;
    Signature: #26                          // ()TB;
}
```

Importing the `Test` class from any Java class causes Eclipse to complain `No completions available`, and `CTRL-Hover` does not work anymore. In order to find the issue, I created and `javap`ed the Java equivalent of the above class, yielding the following results:

**Test.java**:

```
package dyvil.test;

import dyvil.lang.Map.Entry;

public class Test<A, B> implements Entry<A, B>
{
    @Override
    public A getKey()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public B getValue()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**javap Output**:

```
public class dyvil.test.Test<A extends java.lang.Object, B extends java.lang.Object> extends java.lang.Object implements dyvil.lang.Map$Entry<A, B>
  SourceFile: "Test.java"
  Signature: #26                          // <A:Ljava/lang/Object;B:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ldyvil/lang/Map$Entry<TA;TB;>;
  InnerClasses:
       public static #30= #5 of #28; //Entry=class dyvil/lang/Map$Entry of class dyvil/lang/Map
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             //  dyvil/test/Test
   #2 = Utf8               dyvil/test/Test
   #3 = Class              #4             //  java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Class              #6             //  dyvil/lang/Map$Entry
   #6 = Utf8               dyvil/lang/Map$Entry
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               ()V
   #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Methodref          #3.#11         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #11 = NameAndType        #7:#8          //  "<init>":()V
  #12 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #13 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #14 = Utf8               this
  #15 = Utf8               Ldyvil/test/Test;
  #16 = Utf8               LocalVariableTypeTable
  #17 = Utf8               Ldyvil/test/Test<TA;TB;>;
  #18 = Utf8               getKey
  #19 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  #20 = Utf8               Signature
  #21 = Utf8               ()TA;
  #22 = Utf8               getValue
  #23 = Utf8               ()TB;
  #24 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #25 = Utf8               Test.java
  #26 = Utf8               <A:Ljava/lang/Object;B:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ldyvil/lang/Map$Entry<TA;TB;>;
  #27 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #28 = Class              #29            //  dyvil/lang/Map
  #29 = Utf8               dyvil/lang/Map
  #30 = Utf8               Entry
{
  public dyvil.test.Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test<TA;TB;>;

  public A getKey();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Signature: #21                          // ()TA;
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aconst_null   
         1: areturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       2     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       2     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test<TA;TB;>;

  public B getValue();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Signature: #23                          // ()TB;
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aconst_null   
         1: areturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 16: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       2     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       2     0  this   Ldyvil/test/Test<TA;TB;>;
}
```

I managed to track down the issue to be caused by the fact that the class `implements Entry[A, B]`, but I was not yet able to identify the actual problem in the bytecode. Is there anything wrong with the bytecode generated by my compiler? Apart from the package names and Line Numbers and stuff I am unable to find a significant difference between the two classes' bytecode.

---

In case this is not the compiler's fault, I only have the `ANTLR 4`, `Bytecode Outline` and `Eclipse Class Decompiler` plugins.

Comment: Any chance this could be [wtf](http://thedailywtf.com) material?

Comment: Even if the bytecode was wrong somewhere, it is still a really strange Eclipse bug, because the only completions that are still available are `new`, `nls`, `runnable` and `toarray`.

Comment: The real **wtf** was tracking it down to this. I had a relatively long class that didn't let me use Code Completions, I moved the class around, restarted Eclipse, restarted my Computer, until I found out that it was caused by importing a class that was compiled by my custom compiler. At first not knowing it was the class implementing an inner class that caused this.

Comment: What's this "custom compiler" you just mentioned? Does anything show in the Error Log view when content assist fails?

Comment: The custom compiler is  a compiler that I am working on, at it's code can be found here: https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/tree/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler

Comment: And this is what shows up in the error log when using `CTRL+Spacebar`: https://gist.github.com/Clashsoft/50fb49db348d471539b7

Comment: And the `Test.java` has been compiled *within* Eclipse? What happens if you compile it outside, e.g. with `javac` and only import it as binary?

Comment: I don't believe this will change much. This is not a particularly exotic class, and it doesn't have any code that the Eclipse compiler could compile differently than javac. Furthermore, this would not actually solve my problem, as the Java file is just for Bytecode comparison.

Comment: I just realized that the default constructor in my code has a `Signature` attribute while the Java one does not have this (it is not needed in this case as it is just `()V`). Although I highly doubt it, this might cause the problem. But if it does, it is definitely an Eclipse bug, too.

Comment: We agree that this is not an exotic class. Which is why I asked about trying external compilation, because it might be the *importing of externally compiled classes* which makes problems, rather than the actual byte code. If you compile this ordinary java class with `javac` and import the binary into Eclipse without giving it the source code and get the same error, you *know* that it’s not your compiler that matters.

Comment: Turns out this is actually a *really* weird Eclipse bug, as the compilation with `javac` proves... o.O Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get around it? I am having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I solved it by moving the inner class to a new file.